# Events from controls created at run-time

Tags: c#, events, runtime

I am populating a flowLayoutPanel with pictureBoxes at run-time with the following code

```
        for (int i = 0; i < immageArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Image image = Image.FromFile(immageArray[i]);

            pictureBoxArray[i] = new PictureBox();
            pictureBoxArray[i].Image = image;
            pictureBoxArray[i].Width = 256;
            pictureBoxArray[i].Height = 256;
            pictureBoxArray[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;

            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pictureBoxArray[i]);
        }
```

How can do I create the event/events for controls that don't exist yet at design time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pictureBoxArray[i].MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(pictureBox_MouseDown);

...

private void pictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{  
    ....
}
```

`pictureBox_MouseDown` is your mouseDown event handler, of course you can attach any event not only MouseDown and you can do it for any control created at runtime.

here is the list of [events for PictureBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)